# Im trying to do fine-tuning with Keras, but it doesnt work

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, training-data

im trying to do some finetuning with the infamous Diabetic Retinopaty Dataset.
So as i know, im followging those steps

-Train a VGG16 network without head layers, loading imagenet weights and freezing all conv layers for a few epochs.

-Unfreeze some conv layers (the last block) and training again.

The fact is that i always obtain the same acc score again and again. When i train the model with all layers frozen and the imagenet weights, i get almost 0.74. And when i unfreze some layers and train again, i get the exact same score, its seems like it does nothing.

Im using Tensorflow-Gpu 2.0 and Keras 2.3.0.

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import os
import tensorboard
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D, GlobalMaxPooling2D, Input
import pandas as pandas
from tensorflow.keras.applications import vgg16
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import datetime
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import pkg_resources
from keras import callbacks
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
import tensorflow.keras as k


for entry_point in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('tensorboard_plugins'):
    print(entry_point.dist)
#-----------------------------------------------------------
#Corregir el fallo de la CPU
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
#os.environ["PATH"].append("C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.0/bin/cudart64_100.dll")
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
#------------------------------------------------------------
trainLabels = pandas.read_csv("./trainLabels_cropped.csv", dtype=str)

#Hay que añadir la extension a la lista de imagenes
def append_ext(fn):
    return fn+".jpeg"

trainLabels["image"]=trainLabels["image"].apply(append_ext)
#test_data["id_code"]=test_data["id_code"].apply(append_ext)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    zoom_range=[-0.5, 0.5],
    width_shift_range=[-5, 5],
    height_shift_range=[-5, 5],
    rotation_range=5,
    shear_range=5,
    #samplewise_center=True,
    #samplewise_std_normalization=True,
    #fill_mode='nearest',
    validation_split=0.25)


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=trainLabels,
        directory='resized_train_cropped/resized_train_cropped/',
        x_col="image",
        y_col="level",
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=10,
        class_mode='categorical',
        color_mode='rgb', #quitar o no quitar
        subset='training')

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=trainLabels,
        directory='resized_train_cropped/resized_train_cropped/',
        x_col="image",
        y_col="level",
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=10,
        class_mode='categorical',
        color_mode='rgb',
        subset='validation')

basemodel=Sequential()
baseModel=vgg16.VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))
for l in baseModel.layers:
    l.trainable=False
for layer in baseModel.layers:
    print("{}: {}".format(layer, layer.trainable))

headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(512, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(5, activation="softmax")(headModel)

model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)
optimizer=k.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            optimizer=optimizer,
            metrics=['acc'])

#Model Summary
model.summary()

log_dir="logs\\fit\\" +'Prueba'+ datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

parada=callbacks.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='acc',mode='max',verbose=1,restore_best_weights=True,patience=2)
learningRate=callbacks.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='acc', factor=0.1, verbose=1, mode='max', min_delta=0.0001, cooldown=0, min_lr=0,patience=2)
#checkpoint=keras.callbacks.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('\\pesos\\weights', monitor='acc', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True, mode='auto', period=1)


model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=250,
        epochs=20,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=250
        #callbacks=[parada]
        )

train_generator.reset()
validation_generator.reset()

for l in baseModel.layers[15:]:
    l.trainable=True
for layer in baseModel.layers:
    print("{}: {}".format(layer, layer.trainable))

optimizer=k.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-6)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            optimizer=optimizer,
            metrics=['acc'])

model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=250,
        epochs=30,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=250
        #callbacks=[parada]
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

1) Add a couple of more dense layers.

2) Try using other activation functions such as 'tanh' and see if that helps. (ReLU could cause an update in a neuron that prevents any subsequent data points from altering it's weights via the gradient)

Comment: do you mean to use tanh activation only in the dense layers? And how many neurons should i put in those layers

Comment: Yes try 'tanh' activation in the dense layers. 
The right number of neurons can only be found by hit and trial.